# Set selected item in selectlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
IEnumerable<Product> Get();
```

I get items and create collection of this objects

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int? ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }    

Name = new SelectList(Get(), "ProductId", "ProductName", model.Id)

 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.Name)
```

In Model

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public SelectList Name { get; set; }
```

Always on page selected item is first item

How I can set selected item by model.Id?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? What is the problem?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on your controller to see what values the model has?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is:

```
@Model.Name = new SelectList(Get(), "ProductId", "ProductName", model.Id)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Id = smth logic,
Name = new SelectList(Get(), "ProductId", "ProductName")
```

need initialize Id. I didnt do it

Answer (score 0):

To preselect an item in the dropdown, You can set the value to the first parameter you are passing to the `Html.DropdownListFor` helper method.

```
public class CreateOrderVM
{   
    public SelectList Products{ set; get; }
    public int? SelectedProduct { set; get; }
}
```

In your GET action method

```
public ActionResult Order()
{
   var vm = new CreateOrderVM();
   var productList= Get();
   vm.Products =new SelectList(productList,"ProductId","ProductName"); 

   vm.SelectedProduct = 2 ; // Replace 2 with the ProductId
                            // of the Product record you want to be selected.

}
```

And your razor view

```
@model CreateOrderVM
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.SelectedProduct , Model.Products, "Select")
```

Also, as a side note, I am not sure why you have `ProductId` property as nullable int. Typically all the entity records will have a valid id.